# Sys exit return value not showing up when echo in bash

Tags: python, bash, imaplib

So I wrote a python script, login_email.py for reading emails with the "imaplib" and "email" module.

```
import sys
import imaplib
import email

def login(user,pwd):
   mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
   try:
      mail.login(user,pwd)
   except imaplib.IMAP4.error:
      sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   mail_usr = "tester@gmail.com"
   mail_pwd = sys.argv[1] #password will be provided as an argument in the bash 
   login(mail_usr,mail_pwd)
```

And i want to simulate a failed login process so if the login fails, sys.exit(1) will trigger.
In my bash script:

```
function catch() {
    echo "Error"
}
trap 'catch $? $LINENO $BASH_COMMAND' ERR
set -e

password="12345"
python login_email.py $password
echo $?
```

However, when i run the script, i get **no output** as I was expecting **$? to be 1** since I defined **sys.exit(1)** in the python script. What went wrong?

**Edit**
I just found out that the "set -e" that i used to abort the script in case of any script error is causing "$?" to be not echoable.

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be no output - can you show the exact script you're using to launch the python file as well as the console output?

Comment: @PeterGibson sorry but i missed out as i forgot to add the trap statement in the bash script. Apparently i found that the "set -e" is causing $? to not able to be echoed.